# Axios 405 response with Flask cors

Tags: reactjs, nginx, flask

I'm running **react.js** for frontend and **Flask** for my backend.
On development, everything worked fine.

When I built the **react.js** app and hosted it locally with nginx, the following error appeared whenever I tried to contact my API:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405
> (Not Allowed)

This is what I get when I expand the error message on the console:

```
(anonymous) @   xhr.js:177
e.exports   @   xhr.js:13
e.exports   @   dispatchRequest.js:50
Promise.then (async)        
u.request   @   Axios.js:61
r.forEach.u.<computed>  @   Axios.js:87
(anonymous) @   bind.js:9
k   @   sendFiles.js:13
(anonymous) @   fileDownloadMain.js:31
value   @   fileDownloadMain.js:28
hl  @   react-dom.production.min.js:219
Tu  @   react-dom.production.min.js:259
t.unstable_runWithPriority  @   scheduler.production.min.js:18
Ha  @   react-dom.production.min.js:122
Mu  @   react-dom.production.min.js:252
vu  @   react-dom.production.min.js:243
fu  @   react-dom.production.min.js:237
Xu  @   react-dom.production.min.js:285
(anonymous) @   react-dom.production.min.js:289
yu  @   react-dom.production.min.js:244
rs  @   react-dom.production.min.js:289
t.render    @   react-dom.production.min.js:296
97  @   index.js:5
l   @   downloads:1
r   @   downloads:1
t   @   downloads:1
(anonymous) @   main.b7ed8fe0.chunk.js:1
```

My **nginx** configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root "/var/www/htmlTranslate";
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}
```

Running backend with **gunicorn** (server name is main.py)

```
gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:5000 main:app
```

Simplified version of my Flask file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/api/convert_file", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@cross_origin()
def foo():
    if request.method == "POST":
        return "Post request"
    else:
        return "Get request"
```

Comment: Please show us the code for the Axios request.